# Passing dynamic class objects in Java

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

### What's the best approach to pass dynamic class objects as parameters ?

My use case is something like this,

I have a common network class that performs network operations based on the given type and then converts the response into a pojo class. Here's a demo,

```
 public abstract class CommonOperations {

     public void getAuthToken() {
     ......
     AuthToken authToken = response.body();
     success(authToken);
    }

     public void performLogin() {
     ......
     Login login = response.body();
     success(login);
    }

    }

 public abstract void success(Object object);
```

Later, I would like to receive the dynamic object from the overriden class.

e.g.

```
@Override
 public void success(Object requestedObject) {

 AuthToken authToken = (AuthToken) requestedObject;

}
```

or

```
@Override
 public void success(Object requestedObject) {

 Login login = (Login) requestedObject;

}
```

---

Is there any way to achieve this in Java?

I found some similar solutions based on Java Generics and Reflection but I am not sure how to apply it in this context.

Comment: It would be better here to create 2 methods. 1 that takes a ```Login``` and 1 that takes an ```AuthToken```. Or you could let the user pass in a callback as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `instanceof` operator to check the subtype of your `Object` param:

```
@Override
public void success(Object requestedObject) {
    if(requestedObject instanceof AuthToken) {
        AuthToken authToken = (AuthToken) requestedObject;
    } else if(requestedObject instanceof Login) {
        Login login = (Login) requestedObject;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `success` won't receive anything else than `AuthToken` or `Login`, or anything else and in future the number of types won't grow, I suggest you to make overloaded method to enforce better type safety, like this:

```
public abstract void success(AuthToken at);
public abstract void success(Login l); 
public abstract void success(WhateverElse obj);
```

Looking at the given very limited context, I guess the above condition applies, so the method overloading will be your best option.